# Sort alphabetically based on child object's alt text using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a functionality to a toolbar I provide free to players of a game. On the games' equipment page is a list of items in your inventory. I'd like the player to be able to sort them alphabetically by their name.

Unfortunately the only place with the name is at the beginning of a long string of `alt` text on a child `img` element. I've provided one of the divs as an example of the HTML.

So far I've been unable to grab and sort by the alt text and am hoping one of you can help.

```html
<div class="ui-draggable wep arms popme_104960 premium ui-draggable-handle" rel=".wepPop1051" id="104960" style="margin:3px; background:0; padding:0px;">
  <span class="Sellback" style="display:none; font-size:20px;">
    [
    <a class="sellButton" data-sale-type="equip" data-sale-id="104960" href="#" style="color:#553311">Sell</a>
    ]<br>
  </span>
  <img src="https://fe623c4c56cb423a1796-41d97e3e92b81615c7f3767eb26dcf89.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/heroequipment//MM.InvisibilityCloak.Arm.Magic.jpg" style="border:solid 3px #00ccFF;" data-name="Invisibility Cloak" data-id="104960" data-elname="Magic" data-flavor=""
    data-elcolor="00ccFF" data-prem="1" data-sellback="76 Morphons" alt="Invisibility Cloak
    Epic Resist Physical&nbsp;+&nbsp;30
    Super Resist Tech&nbsp;+&nbsp;10
    Super Block + &nbsp;10%" title="Invisibility Cloak
    Epic Resist Physical&nbsp;+&nbsp;30
    Super Resist Tech&nbsp;+&nbsp;10
    Super Block + &nbsp;10%" >
</div>
```

My attempt that just rerenders the divs in their same order :-( in the alphasorted div

```
    "<div class=\"HideFJcontainer\" Id=\"alphBnt\" style=\"font-size:12px;cursor:pointer;\">Sort Alphabetically</div>");

    $("div#drop_extra").append("<div Id=\"alphasorted\" style=\"font-size:12px;\"></div>");

    var $divs = $("div#drop_extra .ui-draggable-handle");
    $('#alphBnt').on('click', function(){
    var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function(a,b){
    return $(a).find("img").attr("alt") > $(b).find("img").attr("alt");});
    $("#alphasorted").html(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
    });
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Anyone have any thoughts on where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!